Is it right to think of the grothendieck group $K(A)$ as the categorification of dimension?
Grothendieck $K$-groups make sense for exact categories I think, but let $k$ be a field and let's assume $A$ is a $k$-linear abelian category, which are supposed to 'categorify' vector spaces over $k$. I would like to think of $K(A)$ as the category concept of dimension of $A$, and for this I would need to have a statement like 'if $K(A) \cong  K(B)$ as groups, then $A \cong B$ in a a non-canonical, axiom of choice way'. But this can't be right because for instance one has a statement like $K(D(A))=K(A)$  (this needs adjectives I think) in general for the derived category of $A$.
But I suppose $D(A)$ should be more analogous to a complex of vector spaces rather than a vector space, and in fact the dimension of a complex, which is the alternating sum of the dimensions of the terms of the complex, doesn't characterize the complex at all, so the interpretation of $K$ could still work, but I don't see how. Maybe by replacing $A \cong B$ by some sort of derived equivalence ? Maybe a way of making this question formal would be to ask wether the category of abelian categories admits a rigid structure but first this is stronger (needs duals) and second I don't think this makes any sense. Thank you.

First let's dispense once and for all with this idea that there is such a thing as "the" categorification of anything. Categorification is not a functor and categorifications are not unique in general; it's an art and not a science to find such things and argue that they deserve to be called categorifications.
One can think of the Grothendieck group as "a" (not "the") categorified dimension in the following sense. The simplest objects that deserve to be called "categorified vector spaces" are the Kapranov-Voevodsky $2$-vector spaces, which is extremely fancy language for categories of the form $\text{Vect}^n$. Then $K(\text{Vect}^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, and in particular $K$ does recover such categories up to equivalence (non-canonically). $K$ is also additive with respect to direct sums (of abelian categories).
However, once you're working with objects as general as arbitrary $k$-linear abelian categories, what you are categorifying is not vector spaces but modules (more precisely, these are "$\text{Vect}$-modules," although we should really require that they're cocomplete for this). So there's no reason to expect the Grothendieck group, or any other dimension-like construction, to be a complete invariant, and it won't be in general.
A different categorified dimension can be obtained as follows. There is a $2$-category, the Morita or bimodule $2$-category $\text{Bim}(k)$, whose

objects are $k$-algebras $A$, or equivalently their cocomplete $k$-linear categories $\text{Mod}(A)$ of right modules,
morphisms $A \to B$ are $(A, B)$-bimodules $M$ over $k$, or equivalently cocontinuous $k$-linear functors $\text{Mod}(A) \to \text{Mod}(B)$ (by the Eilenberg-Watts theorem), with composition given by tensor product, and
$2$-morphisms are morphisms of bimodules over $k$.

This $2$-category admits a symmetric monoidal structure given by the tensor product $A \otimes_k B$ of algebras which corresponds to a kind of "cocomplete Deligne tensor product" of the module categories $\text{Mod}(A) \otimes \text{Mod}(B)$. Every object is dualizable, with dual $A^{op}$, and this allows us to define the monoidal trace of an endomorphism: explicitly, if $M$ is an $(A, A)$-bimodule, then its monoidal trace turns out to be the zeroth Hochschild homology
$$\text{tr}(M) \cong HH_0(A, M) \cong A \otimes_{A \otimes_k A^{op}} M \cong M/[A, M]$$
and in particular the trace of the identity bimodule, which is $A$ regarded as a bimodule over itself, is
$$\text{dim}(A) \cong HH_0(A) \cong A/[A, A]$$
where $[A, A]$ refers to the subspace (not ideal) spanned by commutators. Of course if we repeat this story with "derived" or "$\infty$" everywhere we get the full Hochschild homology. This construction, when applied to the KV $2$-vector spaces $\text{Vect}^n \cong \text{Mod}(k^n)$, also recovers $n$, since $HH_0(k^n) \cong k^n$ since $k$ is commutative.
$\text{Bim}(k)$ describes a $2$-category of "dualizable $\text{Vect}$-modules." You could define a larger category of $\text{Vect}$-modules, say presentable cocomplete $k$-linear categories, which would include examples like $\text{QC}(X)$ where $X$ is a scheme or stack over $k$. And of course the whole story can be derived. All of this stuff can be motivated by topological quantum field theory and the cobordism hypothesis.

Thank you very much for this long and insightful answer.
